# Particles.js como background usando Dash Plotly

Tags: javascript, html, python, plotly

Estou utilizando a biblioteca [Dash plotly do Python](https://dash.plotly.com/) para criar uma visualização de indicadores macroeconômicos, eu gostaria de utilizar como fundo o [Particles.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) pois cria um efeito incrível, eis o [Github explicando como utilizá-lo](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/).

No site do Dash explica [como incluir arquivos Javascript ao seu dashboard](https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources), no entanto, mesmo após fazer o passo-a-passo não obtive sucesso. Eis o que fiz:

```
import webbrowser
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.Div(
        html.Canvas(className='particles-js-canvas-el', 
                    style={'width':'100%', 'height':'100%'}
                   ),
        id='particles-js'),
    html.Script(src='particles.js'),
])

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    webbrowser.open('http://127.0.0.1:8050/');
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Utilizando este código eu consigo apenas um fundo vermelho (o que está correto, pois é a configuração de fundo colocada no style.css), no entanto, as partículas não aparecem.
A minha pasta esta estruturada como:

```
-- front_end.ipynb

-- assets/

    |-- app.js

    |-- particles.json

    |-- style.css
```

Eis o código dos arquivos:

[app.js](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/master/demo/js/app.js);
[particles.json](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/master/demo/particles.json)
[style.css](https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/blob/master/demo/css/style.css)

(Estes arquivos pode ser encontrados na pasta demo do Github citado inicialmente).
Quando eu clico com o botão direito em 'Inspecionar' ele me retorna o erro

**Uncaught ReferenceError: particlesJS is not defined**

Espero que vocês possam me ajudar :)